# Summing up multiple functions based on conditions in multiple arrays in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I am trying to do is if a Product is Enterprise and has been active for over 12 months multiply the revenue in column 4 by the amount of months active. Then sum up all of the rows that meet the criteria together to get a final value. I have tried combining multiple SUMIFS functions together but it gives me the wrong value. I cant have a function as the sum array input in a sumifs fuction but if I could it would work.

[image]

I tried multiple SUMIFS functions and adding the multiplication function in the sum array. I also tried several sumproduct functions.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the formula(s) you've tried, so we can understand the ranges and values.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `SUMPRODUCT`: [sumproduct](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8="Enterprise")*(C2:C8>12)*(D2:D8)*(C2:C8))
```

[image]

Comment: Great!, for this case `SUM` and `SUMPRODUCT` are equivalent

Comment: You are absolutely right! First fought was SUMPRODUCT and after writing all the "inside" didn't realize that simple SUM would be enough

Comment: Thank you so much. Not 100% sure how the syntax works but it did. I have been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this one out.

Comment: @BYork you cannot use `SUMIFS` as you wanted initially, because it is a [RACON function](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions), at the time you need: `(D2:D8)*(C2:C8)` as **sum_range** input argument in `SUMIFS`, since it is not a range, the multiplication converts it to an array, so you get an error, using `SUM` adding AND conditions via multiplication is the correct approach.